# How to get auto generated Id before insertion?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table like the below picture, and I want to get IDwithChar column value concatenating the value with image address, and inserting that into ImageCover column at same query, how can I achieve that ?

[image]

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: You are trying with persist column.

Comment: I am trying to associate the the B1OOOO1 with Image address in CoverImage column at same query

Comment: @jawed is that a database question or a c# question? looks like a DB one, tag the database you are using.

Comment: @jawed Do you want to concate the two column values and update in the cover image column?

Comment: It will **strongly depend** on what the database engine in the background is. SQL Server for instance does ***NOT*** provide a way to get the identity value before it's inserted - the value is **only** provided upon insert - not before.

Answer (score 0):

Try to concate the two column values and Use `UPDATE` statement to update the value in the related column.

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
IdWithChar NVARCHAR(MAX),
ImageAddress NVARCHAR(MAX),
CoverImage NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('B00001','Test Address','Test-Image-Url')
```

Query:

```
UPDATE TEST 
SET CoverImage= IdWithChar +' '+ ImageAddress 
WHERE Your_condition
```

Comment: I want all these to happen in one query, after submitting the form , I want all these happen at once

Answer (score 0):

first you must insert values and get the last identity and then update the field in the record.

```
insert into item values ('test', 'test')
declare @itemId int =  @@IDENTITY
update item set item_code = @itemId  where item_id = @itemId
```